# Help encoding JSON with User Info (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, json

I am currently getting the accountID's from my followers database and outputting them into JSON. But instead of just getting the accountID's from the db, how could I get the user information from another table "Accounts" and append that to the JSON?

My current code to do so is:

```
    $accountID = NULL;
    if (isset($_GET['accountID'])) {
        $accountID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['accountID']);
    }
    else {
        exit("No accountID set");
    }
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Following WHERE `followingUserID` = '$accountID`");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
         $rows[] = $r;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($rows));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go on a limb and assume a few things:

You have 2 tables:

Following

followingId, followingUserID, someOtherColumns

Accounts

userID, someOtherAccountCollumns

Given that, the fix is easy:

```
// Switch this:
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Following WHERE `followingUserID` = '$accountID`");
// By this:
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT f.*, a.*
    FROM Following as f
    JOIN Accounts as a on f.followingUserID = a.userID
    WHERE `f.followingUserID` = '$accountID`
");
```

You will need to modify the column names to the correct ones, but that should help you get all the account info for any given user in the Following table.

Good luck!

Sources:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Thanks for the code. I am pretty new to backend development, please could you explain what the code does?

Comment: In the original sql query you were selecting data from a single table. Using JOIN allows you to relate data between multiple tables. So what the code is doing is: pick a row from table Following, look for its FollowingUserId, then using the JOIN statement, look for a row in Accounts that has the same value in the userID column, relating both rows hence giving you access to the data about that userID in the Accounts table.